# VCF with resonance

Tags: filter, active-filter

I've found this circuit in the LM13700 datasheet. I wonder how can I add resonance? I assume I need to add a feedback network and an op amp buffer. I've read that some synth VCFs sport a band-pass filter in the resonance network. Any ideas how I can add nice, squelchy resonance? 
[image: OTA VCF]

Comment: do you want to design voltage controlled low pass filter? if yes then what is the range of the cut-off frequencies? whether you want a continuously adjustment of cut-off frequency or stepped?    for eg. fcmin=1KHZ fcmax=2KHZ variation step size 100Hz so 10 steps

Answer (score 1):

The LM13700 can support a bandpass filter: -

[image]

There is no formula with design - it comes from the pdf document for the device - possibly the same place as you found the butterworth circuit. My only doubt is that it may not be resonant enough to get the screaming synth sound you might wish for.

Of course you could cascade two together and have a mixer take the lowpass output and mix it with the high pass output to get the blend you might need.

There is another design [here](http://electro-music.com/forum/phpbb-files/wasppercent20filterpercent20clone_2_165.pdf) that appears to get good comments on [electro-music](http://www.electro-music.com/forum/topic-50432.html&highlight=)

There's also another design [here](http://www.birthofasynth.com/Thomas_Henry/Pages/VCF-1.html) that look impressive although I had trouble downloading the circuits - they appeared to take a long while.

This is my favourite though: -

[image]

It came from www.musicfromouterspace.com

In short there are plenty on the internet